# Incorrect behaviour from javascript animated opacity changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, fade

I have a page with several images on it. When the user hovers over any one of the images, I would like a 50% opaque overlay div to fade in with information about the image being hovered over. Here is the code I have in the PHP just now (I've removed the string concats etc for easier reading):

```
<div class="propertyoverlay"
    id="boxnum'.$propertynumber.'"
    onMouseOver="fadein(\'boxnum'.$propertynumber.'\')"
    onMouseOut="fadeout(\'boxnum'.$propertynumber.'\')"
>';
    <h3 class="price">'.$properties[$propertynumber]['price'].'</h3>';
</div>';
```

Which feeds the div ID over to the following commands:

```
function fadein(id){        
    $('#'+id).animate({ 'opacity': 0.5 });
}

function fadeout(id){        
    $('#'+id).animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
}
```

The issues I'm having are:
A. if a user hovers on and off from the image repeatedly and quickly, the fade commands stack up. It would be nicer if the mouseOver and mouseOut commands just overwrote the rest of the cue as soon as they were called.
B. When I hover over the H3 tag nested inside the parent, the mouseOut is called directly followed by the mouse over command, causing the div to fade out and then fade in again straight away.

I'm happy to use Javascript or JQuery to solve this, but, if at all possible, would rather avoid a CSS3 based solution for the time being. Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: Why do ppl always assume incorrect behaviour on JS's part, when the problem is actually the code they write? ;-)

Comment: I meant incorrect in the way that it wasn't doing what I wanted it to do... I assumed my code was the problem. That's why I'm here asking for help and not complaining to JS.

Comment: I know, it's just striking that people phrase their problems/difficulties in such a way that it sounds as though the language is the problem, and not their code...

Comment: Apologies if it came across that way. It was not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: Use the jQuery .stop() method before calling animate, eg:

```
$('#'+id).stop(true).animate({ 'opacity': 0 });
```

B: Try using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in jQuery ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)).  This will fix the issue with child elements triggering mouseover/mouseout.  This means you will have to bind the events with jQuery however, not directly on the HTML elements.

Comment: This is spot on (With the stop(true) correction). Thank you for your time!

Comment: the first true is only needed when you queue multiple animations to execute one after another. In that case it says if the whole queue shall be canceled (true) or only the currently processed animation (false). When you only queue one animation, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start a new `.animate` operation on an element, call the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
 function to stop any animations which are still in progress.

That way, when the fadeout function is called before the fadein operation is completed, it will fade to 0.0 opacity from the opacity value it had already reached.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but I think `.stop()` is what you need! Read more about it in the [official api documention](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)!